# Ubuntu 16.04 server on ODROID XU4 - hangs on shutdown/restart

Tags: shutdown, reboot

I have a ODROID XU4 single board computer, running Ubuntu server 16.04LTS.
On the last days, a strange problem appeared.
When I shutdown or reboot the system (within root) the system hangs. When I shutdown using "shutdown -P", the system shutdown does not complete. When I reboot using "shutdown -r" or "reboot", the system does not reboot.

And when I issue the shutdown command, I can not SSH to it any more (connection refused).
I connected a monitor,and after issuing the shutdown command, I get a blank screen with only the cursor flashing, and stays that way for ever... 
Below is the contents of /var/log/syslog, I don't know anywhere else to look for clues of what's causing the problem...

```
root@odroid-server:/home/bomberb17# cat /var/log/syslog | grep "Jul  3 14:15"
Jul  3 14:14:52 odroid-server rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 9' suspended, next retry is Sun Jul  3 14:15:52 2016 [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jul  3 14:15:01 odroid-server zma_m2[1557]: INF [Saloni: 485 - Gone back into alarm state]
Jul  3 14:15:03 odroid-server zma_m2[1557]: INF [Saloni: 488 - Gone into alert state]
Jul  3 14:15:10 odroid-server zma_m3[1310]: INF [Eisodos: 2755 - Gone into prealarm state]
Jul  3 14:15:34 odroid-server systemd[1]: Stopping Session c1 of user root.
Jul  3 14:15:34 odroid-server systemd[1]: Stopping ACPI event daemon...
Jul  3 14:15:34 odroid-server systemd[1]: Stopped Stop ureadahead data collection 45s after completed startup.
Jul  3 14:15:34 odroid-server systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 0...
Jul  3 14:15:34 odroid-server systemd[1]: Starting Unattended Upgrades Shutdown...
Jul  3 14:15:34 odroid-server systemd[1]: Stopped target Graphical Interface.
Jul  3 14:15:34 odroid-server systemd[1]: Stopped target Multi-User System.
Jul  3 14:15:34 odroid-server systemd[1]: Stopping OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Jul  3 14:15:34 odroid-server systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: automatic crash report generation...
Jul  3 14:15:34 odroid-server systemd[1]: Stopped target Login Prompts.
Jul  3 14:15:34 odroid-server systemd[1]: Stopping Serial Getty on ttySAC2...
Jul  3 14:15:34 odroid-server systemd[1]: Stopping LXD - container startup/shutdown...
Jul  3 14:15:34 odroid-server systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor to "ondemand"...
Jul  3 14:15:34 odroid-server systemd[1]: Stopping Deferred execution scheduler...
Jul  3 14:15:34 odroid-server systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)...
Jul  3 14:15:34 odroid-server systemd[1]: Stopping Snappy daemon...
Jul  3 14:15:34 odroid-server /usr/lib/snapd/snapd[639]: main.go:64: Exiting on terminated signal.
Jul  3 14:15:34 odroid-server snapd[639]: 2016/07/03 14:15:34.592247 main.go:64: Exiting on terminated signal.
Jul  3 14:15:34 odroid-server systemd[1]: Stopping Regular background program processing daemon...
Jul  3 14:15:34 odroid-server systemd[1]: Stopping FUSE filesystem for LXC...
Jul  3 14:15:34 odroid-server systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: start Samba daemons for the AD DC...
Jul  3 14:15:34 odroid-server rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="653" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
```

Comment: I have something similar. I cannot shutdown the xu4 with the power button on the top, and by shutdown in console the blue led does not turn off. I am not sure whether this is a real problem, or it was designed this way, but I am afraid that I damage the SD card if I unplug the power supply in such a "maybe turned on" state. Do you experience the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem too.

As I looking on the Internet, I found a similar problem where have a solution for not XU4: http://mylinuxexplore.blogspot.hu/2011/11/solved-ubuntu-doesnt-shutdown-properly.html

Unfortunately that solution may working with GRUB only (the XU4 has different method to boot the OS).

While I used Ubuntu 15.10 I had a problems with eth0 interface and I found a solution here: http://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?f=95&t=19034

So, I combined about it and as I thought maybe have something with the power-saving / power management function in Ubuntu 16.04 and XU4 too.

I edited the */etc/default/tlp/* file to disable USB auto-suspending mode

From:

```
USB_AUTOSUSPEND=1
```

To:

```
USB_AUTOSUSPEND=0
```

After I restart the tlp service:

```
sudo service tlp restart
```

I can reboot the XU4 without hangings:

```
sudo reboot -h now
```

Maybe important this is only a temporary workaround for this issue I think.
While we disabled USB auto-suspend totally we do not reduce power consumption of device, and the USB devices will have full power all time which increasing the heath of the devices.

If somebody have more usable workaround, please do not hesitate to share with us.

Comment: Instead of USB_AUTOSUSPEND=0 you may [blacklist USB devices](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html#usb) one by one with USB_BLACKLIST="xxxx:yyyy" to isolate the offending device.  Please apply changed settings with `sudo tlp start` as given in the [docs](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html), there is no point in restarting the tlp.service unit.

Comment: @linrunner Do you mean that one of the USB devices force the system to stay turned on? I have an USB keyboard and an USB HDD rack. What can I do with them if I want a proper shutdown?